# How can I pass a function to a route with a form, that gets ran after submission and sets the state in previous Route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

**The Context**

I have a little app where you basically can submit ideas. 
It exists of the `Home` Component that renders the ideas in state.

And another component that the user have access to via a React-Router Route where he sees a little form and can submit a new "idea".

**The Question**

I stumbled upon this problem several times, and now i want to solve it. How can I submit this form, get back to the Home Component, this component grabs the "title" and "body" from the form, creates a new idea and set's the state (rerenders) with the new idea?

**More Information**

In said Home Component I have this function already added:

```
addNewIdea = (title, body) => {
    const newIdea = { id: 2, title, body, claimed: false, likes: 0 }
    this.setState({
        ...this.state.ideas,
        newIdea
    })
}
```

What can I do with it? I can't directly pass it to the "/new/ route right?

So what should actually happen when the user presses "submit" on the form on "/new" route? It should redirect back to home (with the typed in information) and the Home Component should receive this and rerender with a new Idea.

Do I need Redux for this or is this working with blank React?

The `NewIdea` Component looks like this:

```
return (
        <div className="new-idea-container">
            <div className="new-idea-box">
                <h2 className="new-idea-title">Create a new IDEA</h2>
                <input className="new-idea-input-title" type="text" placeholder="Title" value={this.state.title} onChange={(e) => this.setState({ title: e.target.value })} />
                <div contentEditable className="new-idea-textarea" placeholder="Write a detailled Description of your IDEA" onChange={(e) => this.setState({ body: e.target.value })}>{this.state.body}</div>
                <div className="new-idea-btn-wrapper">
                    <input className="new-idea-submit-btn" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick={this.handleSubmitBtn} />
                    <Link className="new-idea-cancel-btn" to="/">
                        <input className="new-idea-cancel-btn" type="submit" value="Cancel" />
                    </Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
```

Just a link that brings the user back when he click on submit button.

Here are my routes:

```
render() {
return (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/new" component={NewIdea} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
}
```

**Another example what I want to achieve:**

Imagine I have the component `Home` that has as state an array of the ideas (objects). 
Now without React Router I would do it like this.

Create a new Component `AddIdea` - this gets passed a callback function as props (the one from above `addNewIdea`). The child component `AddIdea` now fetches the title and body from the user and after hitting submit I run the function from props, which will update the state in the parent component.

But I can't do this in react router. At least not that I know of, so I'm asking, maybe there is a whole other way around this. There has to be, right?

Here is the whole project: https://github.com/dhuber666/Ideas

Comment: Where are your routes?

Comment: Hi, I edited the post with the routes.

Comment: In this case, you could store the state in a parent component of both routes.

Comment: But how can I set the state from another component when I'm at the "/new" route. I will edit the post with another detail what I want to achiev. Maybe it get's more clear

Comment: @Colin I think I get now what you mean. I moved the state and add function to the `App.js` Component and passed it as props like this `<Route exact path="/new" render={(props) => <NewIdea {...props} addNewIdea={this.addNewIdea} />} />` This is working fine now :) Thx
I pushed it to github. Would love to get a little tiny review if I made everything correctly :) - github link is in Original Post at the bottom.